# Unable to install CentOS 7

Tags: centos, usb

I have been trying to install CentOS 7 on a computer with no success so far.

I am able to boot the live USB media, but the problem is the CentOS installation referring the HDD always as /dev/sdb. No matter what I do, the live media is always detected as /dev/sda and the HDD as /dev/sdb. CentOS install properly on the HDD, but when I try to boot from the HDD, without the live USB media, the HDD becomes /dev/sda. The system complains about being unable to find /dev/sdbN partitions.

I do not have the possibility to burn a CD/DVD and loading the image from an optical disk reader.

I have tried with three different USB thumbs, I have created the image by two different methods, the [dd](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey) one as well as using unetbootin. I have messed with all the possible BIOS options related to USB, but I am still unable to get my computer running CentOS 7.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the _udev rules_ in order to reference the devices:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18423187/176974
May be the live version and the installed version do not use the same rules, thus the different references for the same disk unit.

Comment: Can't you edit the bootloader entry temporarily to boot from `/dev/sda`, then boot and change it permanently through the OS?